# Checking that you NSUserDefaults has valid data

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I load my data from NSUserDefaults and it works well.

But I'm a little concerned that the first time the app will be fun and there is no saved data something strange might happen. Is there a way to check that I am not getting back nil values or some kind of standard query to see what you are getting back is a valid answer?

Would putting a

```
ctCountry.isoCountryName = [prefs objectForKey:@"ctCountry.isoCountryName"];
    if (ctCountry.isoCountryName == nil)
    {
       //code to handle noobject returned
    }
```

be a valid and solid way to handle this kinda of work?

Current Code. No checks for data validity.

```
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

ctCountry.isoCountryName = [prefs objectForKey:@"ctCountry.isoCountryName"];
ctCountry.isoCountryCode = [prefs objectForKey:@"ctCountry.isoCountryCode"];
ctCountry.isoDialingCode = [prefs objectForKey:@"ctCountry.isoDialingCode"];
```

Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, checking for `nil` works. Better yet, you could register default values by passing a dictionary of the default preferences to `-[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults]` at every app launch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is not possible to store `nil`, so the only time `ctCountry.isoCountryName == nil` is when the corresponding preference does not exist.